# How can i get total count of a column in one google sheet and get that value to another sheet?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this doubt.

I want to get total number of a Column and get the value to the next sheet in same project.
I need to get the total number of IDs from 'JOURNAL' sheet ,and bring that value to the 'DASHBOARD' sheet.

i have added the link to my sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1apNdW_Y8aLP0i1RTWNUOsMALe06CiJhLspRahf9xbgk/edit?usp=sharing

Apologies ,if i am being a naive . I am beginner to excel and google sheet and honestly i have no idea where to start. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the sheet that you have shared is private, unable to check your file. Based on my understanding of your question I will try to answer

You have Google Spreadsheet with two sheets within that file naming DASHBOARD & JOURNAL

In JOURNAL you have a column with the name ID in column A and you want to get the total count of IDs in your DASHBOARD sheet then you can add the following formula in your DASHBOARD sheet

```
=COUNT(JOURNAL!A1:A1000)
```

This will give the total count of IDs from your other sheet...

Comment: I am sorry for not setting up as needed. Changed it properly. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1apNdW_Y8aLP0i1RTWNUOsMALe06CiJhLspRahf9xbgk/edit?usp=sharingThanks for sggestion and will update.

Comment: yes, try the mentioned solution that will do ur job...